# Why is my script is not adding the integer inside the unordered list?

Tags: javascript

I get similar problem my code is below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <title> this is a test page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
      <script>
        function test(){
            var unorderedList = document.getElementById('list');
            var noList = unorderedList.getElementsByTagName('li');
            var number; 
            alert("this is a test : "+noList[0].value);
            for( int i=0; i<noList.length; i++){
                number = number + noList[i].value;}
            console.log(number);};    
        window.onload=test;         
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>  
     <ul id="list">
        <li> 2</li>
       <li> 3</li>
     </ul>   
   </body>
```

I could not sum up the numbers in the 'ul', can you help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li value="2"> 2</li>
  <li value="3"> 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it correct to say that the innerHTML input is always taken as string ? 

And i tried changing the value to innerHTML, 
but when i do:

for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    result = result + list[i].innerHTML;}
    alert("The total number is : " +result);

The result for input 2, 4, and 6 ( inside the ul) . would be 0246

Do you know whats the problem ? 

so to use that function i need to insert value as well?

Comment: Yes, you are correct use  result = result+parseInt(list[i].innerHTML);

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for isn't `value` it's `innerHTML`.

So, rather then saying

`number = number + noList[i].value`

you should be saying

`number = number + noList[i].innerHTML`

Additionally you need to ensure that number has a numeric value before you attempt to conduct integer addition on it. So rather then saying

`var number;`

you should say

`var number = 0`

EDIT: As per your comment, the problem is that innerHTML comes back as a string.

There are four ways you can deal with this.

Method 1:

```
 list_item = noList[i].innerHTML
 if(list_item.charAt(0) == "0"){
       number = number + parseInt(list_item, 10);
 } else {
       number = number + parseInt(list_item);
 }
```

Explanation 1: You read the string into list_item. You then check the first character in the string to determine the base of the number. This is to ensure compatability with older browser. As of ECMAScript 5, parseInt defaults to base 10, however, older implementations often used base 8 for strings starting with a 0.

Method 2:

```
 list_item = +noList[i].innerHTML
 number = number + list_item
```

Explanation 2: Every type has a Unary Operator. For Integers, this is `+`, so applying `+` to anything will attempt to cast it to a integer, applying `!!` will try to cast it to a `Boolean`, etc.

Method 3:

```
 list_item = Number(noList[i].innerHTML);
 number = number + list_item
```

Explanation 3: The Number object is a constructor object which attempts to parse a number and provide convenience methods. Currently only really fully supported in Firefox, though basic parsing will work in other browsers.

Method 4:

```
 list_item = noList[1].innerHTML*1
 number = number+list_item
```

Explanation 4: Javascript uses Duck Typing (if it walks like a duck and quaks like a duck it must be a duck), so if an item responds to *1, it must be a Number. Has the added benefit of working for floating point numbers as well.

---

Which one do I recommend?

I would probably stay away from the Number constructor for the time being as it isn't really widely known/supported. Generally, I would in fact recommend `parseInt`, as it is the most widely known method, and most developers will know off the top of their heads what the code is doing.

It is worth noting that in Chrome and recent Firefoxes, `parseInt` is also far and away the fastest, however, in older version of Firefox, the Number constructor provides similiar performance benefits (and is supported in full).

IE, however is generally slow, but the fastest are the Unary operator and multiplication(though not by much).

The only really significant argument against `parseInt()` is Opera, where `parseInt` underforms the other methods by a factor of almost 3.

Comment: Just trying to do my bit to give back to the community. God knows I needed help on some pretty basic things when I started. Also, thanks :)

Comment: Thank you. sorry im kinda new in js

And i tried changin the value to innerHTML, 
but when i do:

for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    result = result + list[i].innerHTML;}
    alert("The total number is : " +result);

The result for input 2, 4, and 6 ( inside the ul) . would be 0246

Do you know whats the problem ? 

How can i convert the innerHTML value to integer ?

Comment: pretty epic response to your comment. I hope that answers any/all of your questions about what's going on ^_^